# Participant creation - How to create different participants using golang

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I understand the process of creating participants using hyperledger composer and was also able to tie up those participants with a certificate.

How do I do the same without hyperledger composer ? I am trying to implement the same using go lang. Is it going to be by defining custom structs ? If it is, how to tie a certificate to a particular user

Answer (score 1):

Composer doesn't have a client SDK for Go, only for Node.js, and no plans to do so. The concept of Participants is a Composer construct and is managed by the composer runtime associated with a business network that runs in the fabric.